# Dropdown menu command execution

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drop-down-menu, execution

Is it possible to get a drop-down menu using python's tkinter modules which execute commands when clicked on?

```
# Imports tkinter
from tkinter import *

#creates a root, then a popup and a frame inside to work with
root = Tk()
popup = Toplevel()
popup_frame = Frame(popup)

#creates a labelframe to hold the label and menu
labelframe_example = LabelFrame(root, text="Title For Widget", pady=3, padx=3)
#label providing description about menu
Label(labelframe_example, text="Descriptive label", width=25, height=0).pack()
#options displayed in dropdown menu
options = ["Option1","Option2", "Option3"]
#gains the variable of what is in the menu 
variable = StringVar(labelframe_example)
#sets the inital text for the menu, before an option is selected
variable.set("Pre-option text placeholder") 
#places the dropdown menu in the labelframe, with the displayed text being whatever the variable is and calls the options, expands the menu to size of labelframe
OptionMenu(labelframe_example, variable, *options).pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
#packs frame
labelframe_example.pack()

#creates a function to destroy old frame inside the popup window and recreate it using the information for option 1
def executed_command_1(popup_frame):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    Label(popup_frame, text="Hey Look it worked, a new frame was created for option 1").pack()

#creates a function to destroy old frame inside the popup window and recreate it using the information for option 2
def executed_command_2(popup_frame):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    Label(popup_frame, text="Hey Look it worked, a new frame was created for option 2").pack()

#creates a function to destroy old frame inside the popup window and recreate it using the information for option 3
def executed_command_3(popup_frame):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    Label(popup_frame, text="Hey Look it worked, a new frame was created for option 3").pack()


#unsure how to actually make a way for option specific function to open
option_execution_button = Button(root, text="Open Option", width=25, padx=5, pady=5,               
                         command=lambda:executed_command_1/2/3(popup_frame)).pack()
```

In other words, there are 2 windows, 1 window has a widget with a drop-down menu, and the other should update based on whichever option was selected, the button is not actually necessary if there is a way for this to happen without the button that would be fine too.

I just can't figure out a way to do it, any help is welcome.

Sorry if its hard to understand, if you don't understand I will attempt to clarify further.

Comment: the are errors in your code variables check it and the is no need to call `Tk` twice use `Toplevel`

Comment: So Toplevel works sort of like a frame on its own? So instead of creating the frame to play with I just destroy and recreate the Toplevel? The whole executed_command_1/2/3 thing is because I dont actually know what to do, I'll add some comments though to help.